# how to avoid duplicating code (design pattern)

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have several methods in a class that has the same logic but I can't see how to avoid the duplication?  Each method internally calls another service but otherwise the logic before and after the internal service call are the same, see the code snippet below.

Any help appreciated!

Many thanks,

**code**

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomerDetail(int id)
{
  _log.debug("xxx");

  if(something)
  {
    _log.debug("yyy");
  }

  var results = _internalService.GetCustomer(id);

  if(results == null) 
  {
    _log.debug("no results");
  }

  return results;
}

public List<Customer> GetCompanyDetail(int id)
{
  _log.debug("xxx");

  if(something)
  {
    _log.debug("yyy");
  }

  var results = _internalService.GetCompany(id);

  if(results == null) 
  {
    _log.debug("no results");
  }

  return results;
}

...
```

Comment: where is it that you do something? you could pass a `Func<List<Customer>>` to a method that does all the `if`s and use it as a wrapper. But to get a better response you'll have to add more code, or make the one you are showing more meaningful

Comment: thanks, I had considered that approach, is that the best approach?  I wasn't sure whether passing the function in was not good because you're telling the method what to do from outside it.

Comment: I agree with @Luiso .  You could write a function ``GetDetail(int id, Func<List<Customer>> detailAccessor) {}...`` which contains your common code, using the detailAccessor function passed as argument.

Comment: You may be interested in the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site.

Comment: Doesn't look like much dubplication there. If you really need to, you could put the logging inside the service methods. Or you could create aspects to log on null inputs or null outputs. Read up on [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use delegates:

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomerDetail(int id)
{
    return DoIt( () => _internalService.GetCustomer(id) );
}

public List<Customer> GetCompanyDetail(int id)
{
    return DoIt( () => _internalService.GetCompany(id) );
}

private T DoIt<T>( Func<T> func )
{
  _log.debug("xxx");

  if(something)
  {
    _log.debug("yyy");
  }

  var results = func();

  if(results == null) 
  {
    _log.debug("no results");
  }

  return results;
}
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking.  I was going to do this but I wanted to get a second opinion.  Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Several options, depending on the duplication density:

1. Do nothing. Two-three dups probably not worth time spending on them
2. Make some string constants/readonly fields, if you want. That'll remove some magic strings from the code as well as allow you to neatly change them.
3. Add logging methods to the (2), that's what is recommended if you duplicate hard.